# Render Layer - Blender 2.8

Tags: render-layers, viewlayers

I try to change my workflow from Blender 2.79 to Blender 2.8, but I struggle with the new layersystem. In previous versions you could go to the 'Outliner' window an say to each object by click if it should be shown in the viewport, if it should be restricted from the viewport selection or if it should be renderd. Simular option I also discoverd in 2.8, but how this works together with the new View Layers and how to get renderlayers from different View-Layers. As far as I discoverd it, the 'View-Layers', as a kind of a group of objects, work simular to the old 'Layers' in 2.79. In the Propeties-Window in previous versions you could find the tap 'Renderlayers', an there you where able to group different Layers to one Renderlayer, and use the different Renderlayers in the Compositer, but this last steps, beginning with the creation of Renderlayers I couldn't find in 2.8 and also how to use layers as masklayers like in 2.79.

Is there anyone who had the same problem and could finaly solved it?
Thanks in advance!